# Making android studio plugin, set intellij.localPath to android studio raise "Could not resolve all files for configuration ':z50_ideaPlugins'."

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I must use android studio debug since work requirement, my plugin work in idea android but not work in android studio
it's simple reproduce, create idea plugin with idea > new project > ide plugin

I just change build.gradle settings

```
intellij {
//    version.set("2022.1.4")
//    type.set("IC") // Target IDE Platform
    localPath.set( "${System.getenv("HOME")}/Downloads/android-studio")
    plugins.set(listOf("android"))
//    plugins.set(listOf(/* Plugin Dependencies */))
}
```

my android studio version

```
Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 RC 1
Build #AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515, built on June 14, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 4.18.0-25-generic
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 4
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    IdeaVIM (2.0.0-fix)
    ro.idea.android (1.0)

Current Desktop: XFCE
```

it raise error

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':prepareSandbox'.
> Failed to query the value of task ':prepareSandbox' property 'pluginDependencies'.
   > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':z50_ideaPlugins'.
      > Could not find lib/moshi-1.6.0-ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515-unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins.jar (unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins:android:ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515).
        Searched in the following locations:
            file:/home/roroco/Downloads/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/moshi-1.6.0.jar
            file:/home/roroco/Downloads/android-studio/lib/moshi-1.6.0.jar
            file:/home/roroco/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins/android-ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515/lib/moshi-1.6.0.jar
      > Could not find lib/asm-5.0.3-ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515-unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins.jar (unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins:android:ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515).
        Searched in the following locations:
            file:/home/roroco/Downloads/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/asm-5.0.3.jar
            file:/home/roroco/Downloads/android-studio/lib/asm-5.0.3.jar
            file:/home/roroco/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins/android-ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515/lib/asm-5.0.3.jar
      > Could not find lib/tensorflow-lite-metadata-0.1.0-rc1-ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515-unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins.jar (unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins:android:ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515).
        Searched in the following locations:
            file:/home/roroco/Downloads/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/tensorflow-lite-metadata-0.1.0-rc1.jar
            file:/home/roroco/Downloads/android-studio/lib/tensorflow-lite-metadata-0.1.0-rc1.jar
            file:/home/roroco/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins/android-ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515/lib/tensorflow-lite-metadata-0.1.0-rc1.jar
      > Could not find lib/javawriter-2.2.1-ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515-unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins.jar (unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins:android:ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515).
        Searched in the following locations:
            file:/home/roroco/Downloads/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/javawriter-2.2.1.jar
            file:/home/roroco/Downloads/android-studio/lib/javawriter-2.2.1.jar
            file:/home/roroco/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins/android-ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515/lib/javawriter-2.2.1.jar
      > Could not find lib/resources_en-ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515-unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins.jar (unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins:android:ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515).
        Searched in the following locations:
            file:/home/roroco/Downloads/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/resources_en.jar
            file:/home/roroco/Downloads/android-studio/lib/resources_en.jar
            file:/home/roroco/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins/android-ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515/lib/resources_en.jar
      > Could not find lib/jetifier-core-1.0.0-beta09-ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515-unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins.jar (unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins:android:ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515).
        Searched in the following locations:
            file:/home/roroco/Downloads/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/jetifier-core-1.0.0-beta09.jar
            file:/home/roroco/Downloads/android-studio/lib/jetifier-core-1.0.0-beta09.jar
            file:/home/roroco/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins/android-ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515/lib/jetifier-core-1.0.0-beta09.jar
      > Could not find lib/asm-tree-5.0.3-ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515-unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins.jar (unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins:android:ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515).
        Searched in the following locations:
            file:/home/roroco/Downloads/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/asm-tree-5.0.3.jar
            file:/home/roroco/Downloads/android-studio/lib/asm-tree-5.0.3.jar
            file:/home/roroco/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins/android-ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515/lib/asm-tree-5.0.3.jar
      > Could not find lib/androidAnnotations-ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515-unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins.jar (unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins:android:ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515).
        Searched in the following locations:
            file:/home/roroco/Downloads/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/androidAnnotations.jar
            file:/home/roroco/Downloads/android-studio/lib/androidAnnotations.jar
            file:/home/roroco/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins/android-ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515/lib/androidAnnotations.jar
      > Could not find lib/antlr4-runtime-4.5.3-ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515-unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins.jar (unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins:android:ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515).
        Searched in the following locations:
            file:/home/roroco/Downloads/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/antlr4-runtime-4.5.3.jar
            file:/home/roroco/Downloads/android-studio/lib/antlr4-runtime-4.5.3.jar
            file:/home/roroco/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins/android-ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515/lib/antlr4-runtime-4.5.3.jar
      > Could not find lib/asm-analysis-5.0.3-ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515-unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins.jar (unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins:android:ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515).
        Searched in the following locations:
            file:/home/roroco/Downloads/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/asm-analysis-5.0.3.jar
            file:/home/roroco/Downloads/android-studio/lib/asm-analysis-5.0.3.jar
            file:/home/roroco/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins/android-ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515/lib/asm-analysis-5.0.3.jar
      > Could not find lib/commons-compress-1.8.1-ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515-unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins.jar (unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins:android:ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515).
        Searched in the following locations:
            file:/home/roroco/Downloads/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/commons-compress-1.8.1.jar
            file:/home/roroco/Downloads/android-studio/lib/commons-compress-1.8.1.jar
            file:/home/roroco/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins/android-ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515/lib/commons-compress-1.8.1.jar
      > Could not find lib/libwebp-ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515-unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins.jar (unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins:android:ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515).
        Searched in the following locations:
            file:/home/roroco/Downloads/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/libwebp.jar
            file:/home/roroco/Downloads/android-studio/lib/libwebp.jar
            file:/home/roroco/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins/android-ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515/lib/libwebp.jar
      > Could not find lib/okio-1.14.0-ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515-unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins.jar (unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins:android:ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515).
        Searched in the following locations:
            file:/home/roroco/Downloads/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/okio-1.14.0.jar
            file:/home/roroco/Downloads/android-studio/lib/okio-1.14.0.jar
            file:/home/roroco/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins/android-ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515/lib/okio-1.14.0.jar
      > Could not find lib/trace_agent-ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515-unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins.jar (unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins:android:ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515).
        Searched in the following locations:
            file:/home/roroco/Downloads/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/trace_agent.jar
            file:/home/roroco/Downloads/android-studio/lib/trace_agent.jar
            file:/home/roroco/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins/android-ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515/lib/trace_agent.jar
      > Could not find lib/resources_en-ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515-unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins.jar (unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins:platform-images:ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515).
        Searched in the following locations:
            file:/home/roroco/Downloads/android-studio/plugins/platform-images/lib/resources_en.jar
            file:/home/roroco/Downloads/android-studio/lib/resources_en.jar
            file:/home/roroco/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins/platform-images-ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515/lib/resources_en.jar
      > Could not find lib/resources_en-ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515-unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins.jar (unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins:junit:ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515).
        Searched in the following locations:
            file:/home/roroco/Downloads/android-studio/plugins/junit/lib/resources_en.jar
            file:/home/roroco/Downloads/android-studio/lib/resources_en.jar
            file:/home/roroco/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/unzipped.com.jetbrains.plugins/junit-ideaLocal-AI-223.8836.35.2231.10320515/lib/resources_en.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the reason and solution:

plugins.set(listOf("android")), but default plugin is found in idea dir, the idea dir filetree is diff with android-studio dir filetree, so I can specific plugin absolute path in build.gradle, like following

```
intellij {
//    downloadSources = true
//    type = "IU"
//    version = "2022.3.3" // support android studio flamingo
//    plugins = ["java", "android", "IdeaVIM:2.0.0"]


    // android-studio and idea android src is diff, so use android-studio debug plugin

    def androidStudioDir = "${System.getenv("HOME")}/Downloads/android-studio"
    def androidStudioPlugin = "${androidStudioDir}/plugins"
    localPath = androidStudioDir
    plugins = [
            "IdeaVIM:2.0.0",
            "${androidStudioPlugin}/java",
            "${androidStudioPlugin}/android",
            "${androidStudioPlugin}/gradle",
            "${androidStudioPlugin}/Kotlin"
    ]
}
```